# Como devo estruturar meu banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou estudando MySQL e tenho um sistema de usuário. Quando o usuário loga na conta é possível ele criar anotações. Eu imagino a tabela do usuário certinha, mas e as anotações? Devo criar uma tabela só pra elas e usar foreign keys? O que eu faço?

Comment: Sim cria **uma tabela somente para os usuários**, com usuario_id, nome, e-mail ,... de seguida **cria outra para as anotações** e usa foreign key, dentro dessa tabela insere também o campo usuario_id (neste caso seria a foreign key) que permitirá saber de quem serão as anotações, não sei se me fiz entender, mas basicamente é isso, terás que meter na tabela "anotacoes" um campo igual que irá ligar as duas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seria interessante na tabela de anotações você ter uma chave estrangeira para a tabela usuário, assim você sabe que aquela anotação pertence aquele usuário, ou seja, na tabela anotações você teria uma coluna id_usuario contendo o id daquele usuario que fez a anotação, desse modo todas as anotações que contém esse id possúem a esse usuario. Espero ter ajudado!